# Hide div when array is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an array set up that has something added to the array every time to drop a word into a bucket on the page. I'm trying to show and hide certain div's depending on how many objects are in the array.

My code is:

```
if (test > 5){
    $(".moving").hide();
    $("#done").show();
}
```

This works perfectly except when the page first loads. The div with ID `#done` is still showing when the page first loads and then goes away when the array gets it's first object. (Array starts empty)

Comment: is test = number of objects in the array?

Comment: Can you please show more code or create a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your css just add `#done{display: none;}` That way the div will not show when page first loads.

Or use `#done{visibility: hidden;}` if you just want the div not to be visible.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to the HTML code you could hide it in ready function :

```
$(function(){
    $("#done").hide();
    //Or
    $("#done").css("display","none");

    //The rest of code
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use : `#done{display:none;}` or `#done{opacity:0;}`

Later in code, whenever you want to display it, you may use js/css to change `display` to `block` or `opacity` to `1`.

Answer (score 0):

> The following function will hide done div and show moving div when page
>   is ready after complete page is rendered:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#done").hide();
  $(".moving").show();
});
```

> *Similarly you can use* ***load*** *method in to run a function on page load. but be aware load method is executed before complete page
>   is rendered*

Answer (score 0):

In your  current code, you can add the following at the very beginning of ready function,
$('#done').hide();
or
$('#done').css('visibility','hidden');